# Searching only .xml.gz files in a directory using php

Tags: php, file, gzip

I want to scan a directory which contains many files but I'm in need of files ending with .xml.gz . Below is the code what I've tried but it fails to meet the requirements.

```
$num_files = count(array_intersect(scandir(getcwd()), array('.xml.gz')));
```

I know that I should make use of wildcards but I'm unsuccessful in getting the right output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach (glob("*.xml.gz") as $filename) {

    echo "$filename" . "\n";

}
```